# is there any better approach way to process the array calculation in the conventional image processing?

Tags: c

Now, I'm currently processing the simple image processing program with C.
like this

-declare memory.

```
_Copy_Pixel_ = (BYTE*)malloc(sizeof(BYTE)*(W_Image* H_Image * 3));
_Orgin_Pixel_ = (BYTE*)malloc(sizeof(BYTE)*(W_Image* H_Image));
```

and

```
_Copy_Pixel_[((y*scanlinesize) + x * 3 + 1)] =
(unsigned char)CLIP((
(1) * _Orgin_Pixel_[(y-1)*Picture_x_ + (x)] +
(1) * _Orgin_Pixel_[(y+1)*Picture_x_ + (x)] +
(1) * _Orgin_Pixel_[(y)*Picture_x_ + (x-1)] +
(1) * _Orgin_Pixel_[(y)*Picture_x_ + (x+1)]
) / 4);
```

but I think this is quite a bit to waste the processing time also including HW resources.

Is there any other better way to reduce the resource about time?
so I want to know that how much get the proficient about processing time with pointer in c, if I use the pointer instead just array?

Comment: You question title is very unclear.  The body of the question isn't very clear, either.  There isn't going to be much you can do about the calculation shown.  It seems odd to completely ignore the original value at position (x, y), but that's a separate discussion.  You're unlikely to make much of an improvement to the time.  I suppose you could calculate `y * Picture_x` — call that `y1`, and then use `y1 - Picture_x_`, `y1 + Picture_x_` in the calculations, but I'm not convinced that'll make all that much difference.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I just wrote them for example, my question's point is is there any better way to approach to process the array calculation in the conventional image processing.